# Gmail does not receive my Laravel user verification emails

Tags: laravel, email

I used to have my own email (my domain) to send user verification emails, but my users have reported that they don't have these email, even in the spam box. I have tested, and emails worked well, but not with gmail, they just don't go through gmail (no errors). I decided to change my email to gmail and the result is the same. I tried 2 step authentication and less secure apps turned on, but it does not work. Here is my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Company Name"
```

Any ideas why my emails don't go through Gmail?

**Edit**

Everything works fine with other email services, but my gmail users just don't receive emails from my script.

Comment: You have some glitch on your smtp, how you send the email with code?

Comment: Have you ran php artisan config:cache to re-cache your env file values? It might still be using the old ones

Comment: @Savlon No, other email host like yandex.ru and others get my emails, but gmail does not, and I was wondering why.

Comment: Maybe you need to authorise the gmail account to use smtp through the Google console?

Comment: @EsTeAa it is a default laravel user verification email code

Comment: @Savlon what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something called as app password - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

When you create this, you will get a password and use that instead of your account password.